# How to check if an XMLList is empty in Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, e4x

If I have an XMLList object in Flex, what is the proper way to check to see if the list is empty? Should I just compare the result of `myList.length() > 0`, `myList.toString() != ""` or try another method altogether?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would go with the simple `myList.length() > 0` method.

You can see an example of the `length()` function in the [ECMAScript for XML (E4X) specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-357.pdf) (page 104), which Actionscript implements.